# How to Left Join two Parent-Child tables (i.e. 4 tables)

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

We have the following database structure:

[image: Database diagram]

How can we query for all the data that belongs to a specific client and group? (An example written using Entity Framework 6 would be great.)

We could do something like this:

```
var parentChild1 = dbcontext.Parent1.Include(p => p.Child1).Select(p => p.ClientId = clientId).ToList();
var parentChild2 = dbcontext.Parent2.Include(p => p.Child2).Select(p => p.GroupId = groupId).ToList();
// And the manually join the values in parentChild2 with the objects in parentChild1.
// But there has to be a better way than this.
```

I'm thinking something like this; but can't figure out how to wire up child1(s) with child2(s):

```
void GetData(int clientId, int groupId)
{
    var query = (from p1 in dbcontext.Parent1
                 from c1 in dbcontext.Child1
                 where p1.ClientId == clientId && c1.Parent1Id == p1.Id
                 join p2 in dbcontext.Parent2.Where(p2 => p2.GroupId == groupId) 
                     on p1.Id equals p2.Parent1Id into p2groups
                 join c2 in dbcontext.Child2 on c1.Id equals c2.Child2Id into c2groups
                 from p2g in p2groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 from c2g in c2groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new Parent1
                 {
                     Parent2s = p2g,
                     //Child1s = c2g ??? How to wire up child1s with child2s?
                 };
}
```

Comment: I can probably give you an sql answer, will that help?

Comment: Sure, any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sql statement should return all the data that belongs to a single parent1Id and groupId, from all the tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM Parent1 p1
LEFT JOIN Parent2 p2 ON(p1.Id = p2.Parent1Id AND p2.GroupId = @groupId)
LEFT JOIN Child1 c1 ON(p1.id = c1.Parent1Id)
LEFT JOIN Child2 c2 ON(c1.id = c2.Childe1Id AND p2.id = c2.Parent2Id)
WHERE p1.Id = @Id
```

The child joins are left joins since I assume not all parents have children, but the parents join is an inner join since you need the groupid as well as the parent1 id.

Comment: As a matter of sound principle the join to Parent 2  should be a LEFT JOIN also, since that is the cardinality of the relationship given. That the `GroupId` may be null in consequence of the OUTER JOIN is irrelevant to the selection of JOIN type. Using `SELECT *` is seriously frowned upon for VERY sound reasons, and should never be suggested in an answer without a caveat.

Comment: well, the `select *` is just laziness on my part, I agree it should not be used. However I disagree about the joins between the parents. I must say I considered using left joins for all the joins but then I figured that if a parent have no records with the group id specified the query should not return results unless the OP specified otherwise.

Comment: The ERD supplied by the OP DID specify otherwise. It clearly states that the relationship between the tables is `1 - *`, requiring a LEFT JOIN for correctness. OP is asking this question in large part because he is struggling with the meaning of the ERD symbols. You do a disservice by posting a clearly incorrect response.

Comment: I disagree. one to many relationship does not require a left join unless you want all the records from the left table with or without matching records on the right table. The criteria to select the join type is not the relationship but the desired output of the query.

Comment: Gentleman, thank you for your comments. You are both right, however, in this specific case; p1/c2 are security Permissions and p2/c2 are security Rights. Thus, when creating/editing User Groups we want to return all possible permissions and which of those permissions have been enabled (i.e. converted to Rights).

Comment: @ZoharPeled, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. After experimenting with our database, we only needed to changed two things: 1) change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN (as Pieter Geerkens suggested)  and 2)  move the p2.groupId = \@groupId into the p2 ON condition. Otherwise we weren't getting p1/c1 records if p2 didn't exist., like so: 

LEFT JOIN Parent2 p2 ON (p1.id = p2.ParentId AND p2.GroupId = \@groupId).

Now, how to covert this into EF6 syntax.

Comment: @Kaboo edited my answer to reflect your changes. I have no experience what so ever with EF, so for that part I can't help you.